# Grails 1:m get most relations

Tags: grails, grails-orm, relationship

I'm relatively new to Grails.
I have the following

```
class House {
    Integer number
    Integer maxResidents

    static belongsTo = [town: Town]
} 

class Town {
    String name

    static hasMany = [houses: House]
}
```

I want to get five towns with most Houses. I have seen the possibility to create a criteria but I can't deal with it now. Can someone support?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have a bidirectional association you can do this with a query on `House`:

```
def result = House.withCriteria {
  projections {
    groupProperty("town", "town")
    rowCount("numHouses")
  }
  order("numHouses", "desc")
  maxResults(5)
}
```

This would return you a list of results where each result `res` has the town as `res[0]` and the number of houses as `res[1]`. If you'd prefer each result to be a map giving access to `res.town` and `res.numHouses` then you should add

```
resultTransformer(AliasToEntityMapResultTransformer.INSTANCE)
```

after the `maxResults` line (along with the appropriate `import` at the top of your file).